# In AngularJS Material Design, how to hide overflowed text in the `md-toolbar`?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, angular-material

Something like:

```
    <md-toolbar>
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <paper-icon-button icon="arrow-back" nav-to="{{$root.navTo}}"></paper-icon-button>
            <span flex>{{$root.title}}</span>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>
```

But when `$root.title` is very long, the text will just wrap to several lines. What I want is the effect of `text-overflow: ellipsis;`, but adding it in `<span>` didn't work. So how do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues:

- The span doesn't know the max width your title is supposed to be so it can't tell if it is overflowing.
- Spans can't have an overflow, you will need to change it to a div.

See this crude example I have made:

http://plnkr.co/edit/u0z58vvCDLvTrfZHgkBm

```
<div>
    <div style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; width: 50px">
        THIS IS LONG TEXT TTTTTTTTE EEEEEEEEEEEE EEEEEEEEEEEEEE SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVW
    </div>
</div>
```

Possibly a better solution than relying on CSS to do it blindly is to either make sure you can't enter titles that will be too long. Or coming up with a directive that trims the string for you.

Comment: Thanks Varedis, I tried to use `div` and add the three styles you mentioned but it didn't work. I'm not good at CSS things, but I guess it may be because angularjs has changed some things... I'll just write a filter to limit the length...

Comment: This solution does not work when you don't know the size of the toolbar. E.g. for responsive size. I think this is a tricky problem